# Leer archivo de excel ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Hola tengo el siguiente código que me permite recibir y leer un archivo por **POST** de excel, del cual quiero guardar el valor de celdas especificas, de todas las hojas que del archivo, en variables.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void EXCELREAD(HttpPostedFileBase fx)
    {             

        var x = fx;

        Stream stream = fx.InputStream;
        IExcelDataReader reader = null;

        if (fx.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
        {
            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
        }
        else if (fx.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
        {
            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("File", "This file format is not supported");

        }

        var x1 = reader; //Hasta aquí obtengo todo el archivo



    }
```

Esto es lo que obtengo al analisar el objeto, pero no puedo accesar al workbook.
[image: imagen]
Necesito entrar a la hoja uno, hoja dos ,etc y a celdas especificas, alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Agrega mayor información, por ejemplo, las celdas que quieres de cada hoja. Recuerda, un ejemplo mínimo, reproducible y verificable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si haces los siguiente:

```
DataSet hojas = reader.AsDataSet();
```

Obtienes un dataset con tantas tablas como hojas tiene el libro de Excel. Iterando el dataset y sus tablas obtienes la información que buscad

```
foreach (DataTable tabla in hojas.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in tabla.Rows)
    {
        foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
        {
        // leer item
        }
    }
}
```